# Unit testing a method that returns different values

Tags: django, unit-testing

If a method returns each time different different values,how to do unit testing for that method

i m trying

```
result=someObject.someMethod()
expected_result=someValue
asertEqual(result,expected_result)
```

but in each time the result is different ,so some time the test is clear and some times it fails

Comment: Too broad, what causes some method to always return different values?

Comment: Well why does it return different values? You can typically seed a random generator, and use a time freezegun to introduce more determinism in testing.

Comment: the thing is,the method each time select input data randomly ,so it returns each time different output based on input

Comment: Can you show that `select input data randomly` ?

Answer (score 0):

We have to look for balance between realistic live and test behaviour. In many cases we can simplifications. Take a look at python mock https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html.

For example, return value of someObject.someMethod depends on someOtherObject.dependMethod, if you will fix retern value of `someOtherObject.dependMethod`, you'll can fix behaviour

Your test can look like this:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

....
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
...
    def test_something(self):
        with patch.object(SomeOtherObjectClass, 'dependMethod', return_value=<any known value>) as mock_method:
            ...     
            result=someObject.someMethod()
            expected_result=someValue
            asertEqual(result,expected_result)
            ...
```

See full docs here https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html

I'm sure if You look deeper at realization `someObject.someMethod()` , then you can find out parts of code that raise changable `effect`. Fix that changable parts and you can fix behaviour